# PHP Curl - move to next URL in list if redirected

Tags: php, html, http, curl

I am trying to scrape some info from a site. The URLs to the pages which contain the data i need are simple to get to, but not all the values i input for the "Key" in the URL bring me to a valid page.

For example:

a_website.com/Location.aspx?KeyID=3804

Brings me to a valid page with the data i need.

a_website.com/Location.aspx?KeyID=19

Redirects to "a_website.com/net/search/Default.aspx" and says a default error message on the page such as "you made an invalid selection".

Is there a way that i can tell the script to stop and move to the next URL if it gets bounced to the error page instead of a valid page that contains the data i need?

Code snippit below:

```
function getCommand($key_num) {
    $cmd = <<<EOD
curl "http://www.a_website.com/Location.aspx?KeyID={$key_num}
" --location -c "" > output/{$key_num}.txt &
EOD;
    return $cmd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you [turn off the --location flag to disable redirects](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT), and then turn on the --fail flag, [you should get back the "22" error code](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for missing pages.

Comment: I tried this method but it appears i need to have the --location flag on for the correct pages to appear as well. Is it possible to have the script parse the HTML as it pulls each page and if it sees the error message text to stop and move on to next URL in the list?